# What is the purpose of Console in Sublime text editor?

Tags: ide, editor, development

I want to know what purpose does console solve in sublime text 2. This is invoked by pressing Ctrl+Shift+`

Is this a kind of debugger, or It just helps you to install packages.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sublime Text 2 has Python embedded, and the console let's you inspect the current editor state, and create python code directly in the console to manipulate that state. See the [API reference](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/api_reference.html) to see what you can do.

Sublime Text 2 *extensions* are thus written in Python, and any logging they do ends up on that console as well. So indeed, you can see the console as a debugger as well, if there are any python exceptions they'd be printed to that console.